# Why does this XML validate with this schema?

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

A simple XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
 <code>
  <command name="EXPORT"/>
 </code>
 <module name="DEMO_">
  <keyword name="TEST123"/>
 </module>
 <!--
 <code>
   <command name="321TEST" foo="bar"/>
   <keyword name="TEST123"/>
 </code>
 -->
</root>
```

And a simple schema:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>

 <xs:simpleType name='name'>
  <xs:restriction base='xs:string'>
   <xs:pattern value='[A-Z]*'/>
  </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>

 <xs:element name='root'>
  <xs:complexType>
   <xs:choice minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='unbounded'>
    <xs:element name='module'/>
    <xs:element name='code'/>
   </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>

 <xs:element name='code'>
  <xs:complexType>
   <xs:choice minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='unbounded'>
    <xs:element name='command'/>
   </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>

 <xs:element name='command'>
  <xs:complexType>
   <xs:attribute name='name' type='name' use='required'/>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>

 <xs:element name='module'>
  <xs:complexType>
   <xs:attribute name='name' type='name' use='required'/>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Any number of `<code>` and `<module>` are allowed in `<root>`; `<code>` may contain any number of `<command>`; `<command>` and `<module>` have a single required attribute `name` that must contain only uppercase letters. That's it.

The above XML is wrong by this schema:

- The `name` of the `<module>` element contains an underscore.
- The `<module>` element contains a `<keyword>` element that was never defined or allowed.

However `xmllint` and https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-xsd-validator (at least) still say it's valid:

```
$ xmllint --schema test.xsd test.xml --noout
test.xml validates
```

What am I missing?

If I uncomment the last element, I get errors for invalid `name` and disallowed attribute `foo` (but still not for the `<keyword>` element). So some kind of validation is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake (a common one) is to use `<xs:element name="ABC"/>` in the content models, when you intended `<xs:element ref="ABC"/>`. Your schema is legal, but you have defined local element declarations with no associated type, rather than referring to the global element declarations which do have an associated type.

Answer (score 0):

In the schema, you have specified that the root element may contain an arbitrary number of module or code elements, but you have not specified the type for those elements.

I am not sure what structure you are trying to enforce for you XML document. One possibility could be the following schema, where module and code elements inside the root element have a very specific structure:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>

    <xs:simpleType name='name'>
        <xs:restriction base='xs:string'>
            <xs:pattern value='[A-Z]*'/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:element name='root'>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='unbounded'>
                <xs:element name='module' type ="moduleType"/>
                <xs:element name='code' type="codeType"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name='code' type="codeType"/>
    <xs:element name='command' type="commandType"/>
    <xs:element name='module' type="moduleType"/>

    <xs:complexType name="codeType">
        <xs:choice minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='unbounded'>
            <xs:element name='command'/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="commandType">
        <xs:attribute name='name' type='name' use='required'/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="moduleType">
        <xs:attribute name='name' type='name' use='required'/>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

If you try to validate your XML document against this schema, you will find (among other validation errors) that the value 'DEMO_' is not valid.

Comment: Doesn't the `<complexType>` inside `<element>` specify a type, as in the "root" element? That the XML document is not valid, I know, that's the point, I cannot rely on the schema if a wrong document passes.

Comment: The <complexType> does indeed specify a type for the "root" element. It specifies that the "root" element contains an arbitrary number of elements named "code" or "module". However, the type for the "code" and "module" elements inside the root element has not been specified. Those elements are 'detached' from the definition of "code" and "module" elements later in the schema. You could follow my suggestion or @Michael Kay suggestion to rectify this issue. By the way, the main point of using an xml schema is to detect 'wrong' documents and make sure they will not pass.